# Visual C++ how to convert Datetime to number of seconds since 1970

Tags: visual-c++, datetime, seconds

I am trying to convert Datetime: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y

to the number of seconds since 1970 using Visual C++.

I searched many solutions but could not make any of them work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a `TimeSpan` of the difference between the two dates. Something like this:

```
DateTime dtDateYouWantToConvert = /* .... */
DateTime dtReference(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

TimeSpan tsDiff = dtDateYouWantToConvert - dtReference;

// calculate number of seconds (including fractional) since 1/1/1970
double dSeconds = tsDiff.TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Another small question, how do I convert back from the number of seconds to time as string?  I mean from dSeconds back to DateTime?

Comment: Just add (or subtract) the `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` and you'll get a `DateTime` you can format, or use `TimeSpan.ToString(format)` to get a string for the `TimeSpan`.

Comment: how do I convert from number of seconds to DateTime?

Comment: I found an answer that works, I don´t know if there is something more simple:  time_t ts;
double dSeconds = tsDiff.TotalSeconds;
ts = (time_t) dSeconds;           
struct tm *tm_ts = gmtime(&ts);  
char str_temp44 [80] = "";                      
strftime (str_temp44, 80, "%a, %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", tm_ts);